# How to wrap an ink::env::Error in a Custom Error?

Tags: polkadot, ink, smart-contract, pallet-contracts

In my contract, I have a requirement to call messages from external contracts without knowing their specific identities beforehand. To achieve this, I utilize the call builder, enabling the execution of transactions at a low level. Since these transactions may encounter failures, I adopt the `try_invoke` method, which facilitates error handling. The `try_invoke` method can return two types of errors:

1. Errors arising from the underlying execution environment (`ink::env::Error`).
2. Errors stemming from the programming language itself (`ink::LangError`).

Below is the section of code where I implement this functionality:

```rust
            ...
            // Fetch the transaction
            let tx = self.get_tx(tx_id).expect("This should never fail because we are checking the tx_id before calling this function");

            let tx_result = build_call::<<Self as ::ink::env::ContractEnv>::Env>()
                .call(tx.address)
                .gas_limit(tx.gas_limit)
                .transferred_value(tx.transferred_value)
                .call_flags(CallFlags::default().set_allow_reentry(tx.allow_reentry))
                .exec_input(ExecutionInput::new(tx.selector.into()).push_arg(InputArgs(&tx.input)))
                .returns::<Vec<u8>>()
                .try_invoke();

            // Instead of just returning a custom Error we could return the error from the call
            let result = match tx_result {
                Ok(Ok(bytes)) => TxResult::Success(bytes),
                Ok(Err(e)) => TxResult::Failed(Error::LangExecutionFailed(e)),
                Err(e) => TxResult::Failed(Error::EnvExecutionFailed(e)), // Here is where i need to wrap the error in order to provide useful information about the tx failure
            };
            ...
```

I defined two custom errors that serve as wrappers for the errors thrown by the `try_invoke` method.

```rust
#[derive(scale::Encode, scale::Decode)]
    #[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(scale_info::TypeInfo))]
    pub enum Error {
        /// Env error encountered when executing the transaction
        EnvExecutionFailed(ink::env::Error),
        /// Transaction executed but Lang error encountered
        LangExecutionFailed(ink::LangError),
        ...

    }
```

However, during compilation, I encountered the following errors:

```
The trait WrapperTypeEncode is not implemented for ink::ink_env::Error.
```

```
The trait WrapperTypeDecode is not implemented for ink::ink_env::Error.
```

I've come to understand that the error is being thrown because `ink::env::Error` does not implement `scale::Encode` and `scale::Decode` traits. I'm wondering if there's a way to manually implement these traits, or if there is another solution.

Comment: this is as far as i got with it https://github.com/ltfschoen/XCMTemplate/blob/47942a8eb9dbb10eb3c8b188606c8e4a2c3c8b6a/dapps/ink-rust/rand-future/lib.rs#L153

Comment: I am handling similar situation here https://github.com/swankyhub/rmrk-lazy-mint/blob/507552ced20d948b6acb34eb75855f84f30357fa/rmrk_proxy/proxy.rs#L126. I hope it helps

Comment: @LukeSchoen Hey, thanks for the code! I checked it out, and it seems that for now using a match expression for handling the specific errors and then throwing custom errors is the best option. I really appreciate your help. Thanks!